# Webgl throws different error in browsers

Tags: javascript, webgl

Im am learning webgl I made an application to read PLY files and render them in with webgl. The application works fine in Chrome, but when I run it in safari or in Firefox it doesn't work. I tested it in 2 more computers and it just worked in one. Each the browsers throw different errors. This is the error in safari:

```
[Warning] WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: drawElements: attempt to access out of bounds arrays
```

In Firefox I get the following error:

```
Error: WebGL: drawElements: no VBO bound to enabled vertex attrib index 2!
```

The same code in Chrome works perfectly. Using the debugger in the different browsers I could not find a difference in the buffers and the arrays used for drawing.

Here is the code:

```
   function initShaders() {
        var fragmentShader = getShader(gl, "shader-fs");
        var vertexShader = getShader(gl, "shader-vs");

        shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

        if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
            alert("Could not initialise shaders");
        }

        gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

        shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

        // shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexColor");
        // gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexColorAttribute);

       shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aTextureCoord");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute);

        shaderProgram.normalCoordAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexNormal");
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.normalCoordAttribute);

        shaderProgram.pMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uPMatrix");
        shaderProgram.mvMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uMVMatrix");
        shaderProgram.nMatrixUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uNMatrix");
        shaderProgram.samplerUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uSampler");
        shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uAmbientColor");
        shaderProgram.lightingDirectionUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uLightingDirection");
        shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "uDirectionalColor");
    }

    function initPLYObjectBuffers (ply_obj) {
        ply_obj.vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ply_obj.vertexBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(ply_obj.vertexArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        if(ply_obj.hasNormal){
            ply_obj.normalBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ply_obj.normalBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(ply_obj.normalArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        }

        if(ply_obj.hasTexture){
            ply_obj.textureBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ply_obj.textureBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(ply_obj.textureArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        }

        // if(ply_obj.hasColor){
        //     ply_obj.colorBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        //     gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, ply_obj.colorBuffer);
        //     gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
        // }

        ply_obj.indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ply_obj.indexBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(ply_obj.indexArray), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
    }

function drawPLYObject(obj){

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.vertexBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, obj.vertexItemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.normalBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexNormalAttribute, obj.normalItemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.textureBuffer);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.textureCoordAttribute, obj.textureItemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, myTexture);
        gl.uniform1i(shaderProgram.samplerUniform, 0);

        gl.uniform3f(
            shaderProgram.ambientColorUniform,
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambientR").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambientG").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("ambientB").value)
        );

        var lightingDirection = [
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightDirectionX").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightDirectionY").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("lightDirectionZ").value)
        ];
        var adjustedLD = vec3.create();
        vec3.normalize(lightingDirection, adjustedLD);
        vec3.scale(adjustedLD, -1);
        gl.uniform3fv(shaderProgram.lightingDirectionUniform, adjustedLD);

        gl.uniform3f(
            shaderProgram.directionalColorUniform,
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("directionalR").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("directionalG").value),
            parseFloat(document.getElementById("directionalB").value)
        );

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, obj.indexBuffer);
        setMatrixUniforms();
        gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, obj.getIndexCount(), gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
}
```

Most of the code is from a tutorial. The only addition is the ply_obj, which contains the arrays for the vertex, normals, and texture of the obj in the file. I also save there the reference for the different buffers to use later in the drawPLYObject function. The code that generates the ply_obj is from this page http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_ply.html. I just changed it to work with plain webgl without three.js.

The error always appears in this line:

```
         gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, obj.getIndexCount(), gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

I checked the arrays and they are correct and are the same in all browsers. I don't know what else could be the problem. Thank you in advance. If you need more information i would gladly provide it.

Comment: Have you tried using [the WebGL Inspector](http://benvanik.github.io/WebGL-Inspector/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turned out to be really dumb. I was referencing a variable with another name. Somehow chrome managed to run the program with this error.